# fa-fa icon not showing on a mapped domain of the same site

Tags: wordpress, cors

I am using fa-fa icons on this site: http://www.naturopathically.co.uk

a mapped domain to this same site is http://www.naturopathically.fr

but the icons are not appearing here at all only on the .co.uk

can clues as to why this could be  - many thanks

Comment: `Font from origin 'http://www.naturopathically.co.uk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.naturopathically.fr' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score -1):

Try the generated code first. for example if you go to the icon sites which supports html5, will give you a sort code for the icon, for example: https://octicons.github.com/ like this.. you get a code for example, https://octicons.github.com/icon/alert/ you can use this for additional option.

also sometimes the fa fa-icon dont works, only try to input, fa-icon or just icon name, as shown on git.

Hope this one helps you!